# Getting translated version of Menu

Tags: i18n-l10n, navigation

I'm trying to get translated variant of Manu, but I can't make it work. 
This is code of what I'm trying to do, but this is for content node.

```
$entitytype_manager = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager');
$storageNode = $entitytype_manager->getStorage('node');
$node = $storageNode->loadByProperties(['title' => $title_fr]);
$node->getTranslation('fr');
```

Anyone know how I could do this?

**EDIT**

As someone said, I was not clear enough. 
Above code is working example for content, but I can't figure out how to make analog code to this but for Menu.

Comment: Hi. It's unclear to me what you are asking. You mentioned getting translated menu link content, but your code references loading nodes. It may help to be more specific about how the menu content relates to the node.

Answer (score 1):

Use /admin/config/regional/language/detection to set how language is detected. Add the language switcher module someplace to let a user change language. I find that when I switch a language, menu items adjust to the current language.  So create the menu item to /somelink and change my language to Japanese, change the link to /ja/somelink when the menu generates again.

I worry about the path you're going down... what if a node hasn't been translated?

Comment: Hi, Eahonet. This will not be on user side, this is for backed and connecting website's menu system with external mobile app. That is why I need lets say FR version of menu, for FR version of an app. Menu will be provided with API. I'm able to provide localized version of menu by using site/fr/api/menu, but I can't find solution for site/api/menu?language=fr.